# How can I start node with a nested app.js file in OSX?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

In windows I was used to being able to call node and pass it a file to execute. In this case I want to execute app.js webserver but I don't want to host it in the root of my directory I want to keep it in an app_start folder.

I am using Webstorm But I just cannot get my webserver to start. I have put a comment in the line that I have changed in the image below but to explain...when I have...

app_start/app.js the server will not start but when I have bin/www the server starts. But as soon as I nest it and change this setting it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to change the default location of the app.js file with node and webstorm?

[image]

Can anyone tell me exactly what bin/www is? 
Why with the default project template there is no explicit call to app.js?
How I can modify Webstorm to allow pointing to a different file to start my node webserver?

Comment: looks like you are using an [express](http://expressjs.com/) web server and upgraded express from 3.x to 4.x . In 3.x you started the server with `node app.js`, in 4.x it's somehow modularized: you have the express app in app.js and a wrapper in bin/www that actually starts the web server - you can use `bin/www` from your command line directly (no need to execute app.js with node).

Comment: So how do I change the location of app.js? Also I tried doing what I wanted from the terminal command line and it worked. However it didn't work from Webstorm.....

Comment: The bin/www script requires the app.js file as `var app = require(../app)`. If you change this reference (i.e. to `require(/your/absolute/path/to/this/app.js)` in bin/www, it should work. Is this what you need?